Unable to Connect Python Application to Docker PostgreSQL and AWS Profile Not Found
I am experiencing two main issues with my Python application, which uses PostgreSQL within Docker running on WSL on Windows 11 and AWS:
Database Connection Issue
Error: could not translate host name "0.0.0.0" to address: Name or service not known
Context: When running python app/main.py, the application fails to connect to the PostgreSQL database running inside a Docker container.
Details:
I have a Docker container running PostgreSQL, mapped to port 5433 on localhost.
Environment variables for database connection are set as follows:
export DB_HOST="localhost"
export DB_PORT="5433"
export DB_NAME="" (omitted)
export DB_USERNAME=""  (omitted)
export DB_PASSWORD="" (omitted)

AWS Credentials Issue
Error: ProfileNotFound: The config profile ( (omitted) ) could not be found
Context: The application fails to find the specified AWS profile when trying to use AWS services through Boto3.
Details:
AWS environment variables are set as follows:
export AWS_SHARED_CREDENTIALS_FILE="/home/ (omitted)/.aws/credentials"
export AWS_CONFIG_FILE="/home/ (omitted)/.aws/config"

1. Database Connection Issue
Initial Setup:
Docker container for PostgreSQL was set up and running.
Docker command used to run the PostgreSQL container:
docker run --name my_postgres -e POSTGRES_USER=(omitted) -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=(omitted) -e POSTGRES_DB=(omitted) -p 5432:5432 -d postgres
Error Encountered:
The application threw the error: could not translate host name "0.0.0.0" to address: Name or service not known.

Troubleshooting Steps:
Docker Port Conflict:
Realized the default PostgreSQL port 5432 might be in use. Changed the port mapping to 5433:
docker run --name my_postgres -e POSTGRES_USER=(omitted) -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=(omitted) -e POSTGRES_DB=(omitted) -p 5433:5432 -d postgres
Stopped Local PostgreSQL Service:
Stopped the local PostgreSQL service to avoid conflicts using:
sudo service postgresql stop

Verified Docker Container:
Verified the container was running and mapped to the correct port:
docker ps

Output:
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE      COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS         PORTS                                       NAMES
9c8d0a1647ed   postgres   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   8 seconds ago   Up 7 seconds   0.0.0.0:5433->5432/tcp, :::5433->5432/tcp   my_postgres

Current State:
Despite setting DB_HOST to localhost and mapping the container port, the application still fails to connect with the error: could not translate host name "0.0.0.0" to address: Name or service not known.
2. AWS Credentials Issue
Error Encountered:
The application threw the error: ProfileNotFound: The config profile ( (omitted) ) could not be found.
Troubleshooting Steps:
Environment Variables:
Set the AWS environment variables correctly:
export AWS_SHARED_CREDENTIALS_FILE="/home/(omitted)/.aws/credentials"
export AWS_CONFIG_FILE="/home/(omitted)/.aws/config"

Verified AWS Config Files:
Checked the content of the AWS credentials and config files to ensure they were correctly formatted and located.
Current State:
Despite setting the environment variables and verifying the config files, the application still fails to recognize the AWS profile, or if it seems to have them set it returns a connection issue.
This is a result of running the main.py script. The main.py script is used to manage a PostgreSQL database. It can upgrade or downgrade the database schema using Alembic.
Request for Help
I would appreciate any guidance on resolving these issues:

What might be causing the database connection problem?
Why is the AWS profile not being recognised despite setting the environment variables?

Environment

Windows 11
Ubuntu WSL2
Docker
PostgreSQL
Python 3.9
Boto3 for AWS interactions

If you need any more details please let me know.
Thank you!

Please split this into two separate questions.  It seems like the issue around the database is an issue only starting the database container, and has nothing to do with your application code?

I believe the two problems are related, with the lack of verification it seems the connection fails and vice versa. Whilst i see your point i wanted to allow people to understand the issue i am having which is bouncing between both error messages.

This answer only relates to the first question. Since you are not using docker-compose but manually creating the containers, you need to create a docker network and add your database container to the network as well as your application container. Afterwards you can find out the IP of the database container inside the network.

Create a network: docker network create yournetworkname
Add both containers to the network: docker network connect yournetworkname containerhashofdb & docker network connect yournetworkname containerhashofapplication
Inspect network to find out the IP of your DB: docker network inspect yournetworkname
Find the IP of your DB container and use this IP inside your application.

(Those instructions are MacOS and Linux only, since you are on Windows please check the corresponding Windows ones)

Thanks for your suggestion but the same errors occur... I have been wondering if its to do with AWS/boto not finding the credentials where it typically would look for the corresponding OS, even if a symbolic link is used it still cannot find them perhaps because the path it searches for on Linux is different to where its stored on my Windows machine - i am not entirely sure HOME exists on my machine in the same way it would on Linux. The paths i am referring to: The credentials file is located at ~/.aws/credentials on Linux or macOS, or at C:\Users\ USERNAME .aws\credentials on Windows.
